Show that $\frac{1}{(a+b)(c+1)}+ \frac{1}{(c+b)(a+1)}+ \frac{1}{(a+c)(b+1)} \leq \frac{3}{4}$
The problem
Let $a,b,c\in (0, \infty)$ with $abc=1$. Show that the following inequality holds:
$\frac{1}{(a+b)(c+1)}+ \frac{1}{(c+b)(a+1)}+ \frac{1}{(a+c)(b+1)} \leq \frac{3}{4}$
my idea
First of all I used $abc=1$ to get rid of the every intruder : $\frac{1}{(a+b)(c+1)}= \frac{abc}{(a+b)(c+abc)}=\frac{abc}{c(a+b)(ab+1)}= \frac{abc}{c(a+b)(ab+1)}= \frac{ab}{(a+b)(ab+1)}$
From here I don't have any other idea. Maybe we can use some known inequality such as AM-GM
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(a + b)(c + 1)} &= \frac{1}{(a + b)\left (\frac{1}{ab} + 1\right )} = \frac{1}{\left (a + \frac{1}{a}\right ) + \left (b + \frac{1}{b}\right )}
\end{align*}
and similar for the other two terms. Now note that $x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ for all $x > 0$ (by AM-GM for example), so
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\left (a + \frac{1}{a}\right ) + \left (b + \frac{1}{b}\right )} &\leq \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
Hence, we conclude
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(a + b)(c + 1)} + \frac{1}{(b + c)(a + 1)} + \frac{1}{(c + a)(b + 1)} &\leq \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}

Setting $a = \frac{x}{y}, b = \frac{y}{z}, c = \frac{z}{x}$ (WLOG, since $abc = 1$), we wish to prove the equivalent
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z}\right)\left(\frac{z}{x} + 1\right)} \\ = \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x^2z + z^2x + y^2x + y^2z}{xyz}\right)} \\ =\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{xyz}{x^2z+z^2x+y^2x+y^2z} \le \frac{3}{4}
\end{equation}
But by AM-GM, $x^2z + z^2x + y^2x + y^2z \ge 4\cdot \sqrt[4]{x^4y^4z^4} = 4xyz$,
so $$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{xyz}{x^2z+z^2x+y^2x+y^2z} \le \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{xyz}{4xyz} = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$$
As required.
